# How to display DIV to full width on a page that has a bootstrap class 'col-md-6'?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I am trying to display divs side by side on a page. However, if there is only one `col-xs-12 col-md-6` div class on the page, then I am trying to display it full width(100%) rather than 50%. Currently it's using only 50% even if there is only one `col-xs-12 col-md-6`. The HTML is coming from MVC, so this HTML is fixed. Is there a way to do this using CSS or JavaScript/jQuery? I was thinking the following javascript(below) will do the trick but it doesn't.

Here is the my HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 textcontent">
   </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 service">
   </div>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 textcontent">
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.col-md-6{
width50%;
}
```

JavaScript

```
if ($('.col-xs-12.col-md-6').length == 1) {
    $('.col-xs-12.col-md-6').toggleClass(".col-xs-12.col-md-12")
    }
```

Comment: what does this question has to do with jquery, javascript or sass?

Answer (score 0):

The Bootstrap grid system is based in a 12 column model. You can just use col-12 to say a column fill all container width.

Try this:

```
<div class="col-12 textcontent">
   </div>

<div class="col-12 service">
   </div>

<div class="col-12 textcontent">
   </div>
```

Here the [documentation about grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) with bootstrap and breakpoints if you want to apply different column configuration depending of the device screen width.

Comment: Well this class doesn't work because, I want to display the divs side by side if there more than one  `col-xs-12 col-md-6` divs. I want it to display full width only if there one `col-xs-12 col-md-6`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that you're locked into Bootstrap. This could easily be done with Flexbox. Addressing your specific question and code you posted, there's just a small error with your class toggle.

```
if ($('.col-xs-12.col-md-6').length == 1) {
    $('.col-xs-12.col-md-6').toggleClass("col-xs-12 col-md-12");
}
```

When adding the class names, you don't want to add the "**.**" and you want the class names separated just like they appear in the HTML. What you were doing was trying to add class="**.col-xs-12.col-md-12"** instead of class="**col-xs-12 col-md-12"**.

I presume since you're using Bootstrap, you also won't need that css definition for .col-md-6 since Bootstrap should already have that defined for you.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need to do in JavaScript is **remove** the class "`col-md-6`".

```
if ($('.col-xs-12.col-md-6').length == 1) {
  $('.col-xs-12.col-md-6').removeClass("col-md-6")
}
```

The `.col-xs-12` applies to every screen size from `xs` up, and is overrode by `.col-md-6` for screen size `md` and up. So you just stop the override from happening by removing the class.